# How about a homomorphic integer sorting in a MPC context?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation, ntru

I want to implement the ATV-FHE scheme as described by Adriana López-Alt, Eran Tromer, Vinod Vaikuntanathan: [*On-the-Fly Multiparty Computation on the Cloud via Multikey Fully Homomorphic Encryption*](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/094.pdf) ([ePrint](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/094) revised 2014, originally in [Proceeding of STOC 2012](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2213977.2214086)); and based on it I want to compare homomorphically a vector of integers. Would this be a valuable application, something that is both new and useful ?

By new, I mean that the integer comparison I want to implement is for a multikey FHE. For FHE there are some very good implementations that deal with homomorphic integer comparison and sorting.

Comment: Any idea of why the scheme has been [cited](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/039) as ATV rather than LTV? The [first author](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~lopez/) seems to refer to herself by the name López-Alt.

Comment: Are you sure sorting was ever introduced with FHE? "Bit-Slice Auction Circuit" (IACR 2002/189) could be a hint on comparing operation.

Comment: I have come across some papers that deal with homomorphic sorting, like Recent Advances in Homomorphic Encryption http://www.researchgate.net/publication/258792316_Recent_Advances_in_Homomorphic_Encryption_A_Possible_Future_for_Signal_Processing_in_the_Encrypted_Domain and _Low Depth Circuits for homomorphic sorting_ which can be found here https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/274.pdf